# Checking if the file is already in use before opening (network drive, C#)

Tags: c#, file, readonly

Does there exist any way in .Net to check before opening if a file (on a local network drive) is already in use?

Comment: Thanks to all. But as liggett78 had specified the question is not about being able or not being able to open a file. It is about knowing    if the file is used by smth else. 
I'm not sure that means to do that exist at all. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well, if you say "in use" it would mean the original app that open the file will most like not allow concurrent edit. If it does allow concurrent edit, that means either it can handle live changes or it doesn't need to lock the file in the first place. The latter would mean it's not "in use".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to access it and if it failed, you either don't have required permissions (which you can check with GetAccessControl) or it's locked by another process.

But I don't think there is any reliable measure to distinguish a lock and a permission failure (since you might be able to read the file, but not able to check the permissions). Even Windows' error message says you either don't have permission or it's being used by another process.

You can use WMI `CIM_DataFile` class to query `InUseCount` for a specified data file.

If you're looking for a programmatical equivalent to `lsof` utility in Linux, to find out all open files by a given **local** process, you could try using `Win32_Process` WMI class through `System.Management` namespace. You could issue a WMI query to look up the file name in all open files being used by all local processes too see if it's there or not. Alternatively, you could P/Invoke and use `NtQuerySystemInformation` API directly to accomplish the same task.

Comment: What if the file is already open with FileShare.ReadWrite? Then you can still open it without any error on your side, but it is already in use

Comment: You could try to rename the file... if it was already in use, it would throw an exception.
But that wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: @Nelson, If you have just read permission for the file, can you do it?! Even if it's not locked, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @liggett78, if you try to acquire an exclusive lock (open it exclusively), it'll fail even if it's already open with shared lock.

Comment: I'm afraid that `InUseCount` is always `null`. Maybe using `Writable` property instead would be better.

Answer (score 2):

This will do. FileShare.None as mentioned in MSDN :

> None : Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

```
File.Open(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

EDIT : Remember to wrap in a Try/Catch block, and using FileShare.None actually means you want to open the file exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool CanReadAndWrite(string path)
{
    var perm = new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(
         System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write |
         System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read,
         path);
    try
    {
         perm.Demand();
         return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Checks to see if you can read and write to a file.

Comment: Just remember that the file can still be locked after calling this function, but before you try to open it.  

So there is currently no 100% solution except for trying to Open the file and then handling the exception, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path). Surround it in a try/catch block, and if it is already open for writing somewhere else, you will get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: You can open a file for write successfully if another process specified that the file be shared-for-write (FileShare.Write).

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will help:

FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always avoid relying on file accessibility checks. The reason is that it might be, and then it may change just a couple of cycles before you access it.

Instead, just try to open it and see if you have any errors.